# What's the quickest way to find a co-op match?

Tags: dota-2

Co-op vs. Bots does not seem to be a popular game mode anymore, but it's one I enjoy. However, with the various setup options available (bot difficulty, bot AI, base location) there are dozens of permutations available, and each permutation, presumably, places you into a different queue.

Which permutation of match settings should be used to minimize the queue time of a co-op vs. bots match?